# Downloading Images with Urllib in Python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I ran the following code to download an image using `urllib` module. But I ended up facing some errors as below.

```
import urllib.request
import random

def downloader(image_url):    
    file_name = random.randrange(1,10000)    
    full_file_name = str(file_name) + '.jpg'    
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, full_file_name)    
    url = input("URL ")   
    downloader(url)
```

Error Message:

> File "img_down.py", line 1, in 
>       import urllib.request   File "C:\Users\shekh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py",
>   line 88, in 
>       import http.client   File "C:\Users\shekh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 71, in 
>       import email.parser   File "C:\Users\shekh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\email\parser.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser   File "C:\Users\shekh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\email\feedparser.py",
>   line 27, in 
>       from email._policybase import compat32   File "C:\Users\shekh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\email_policybase.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from email import header   File "C:\Users\shekh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\email\header.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       import email.quoprimime   File "C:\Users\shekh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\email\quoprimime.py",
>   line 44, in 
>       from string import ascii_letters, digits, hexdigits ImportError: cannot import name 'ascii_letters'

Comment: do you have any file named `string.py` in the folder?

Comment: @Auxilus in which folder ?? The folder I'm executing the file or the folder in which the lib is present ??

Comment: Is the file in `import path` of python? can be your current folder or lib folder cz if you have string.py in current folder, then your code will try to import that file instead of standerd string.py .

Comment: @Auxilus thanks, changed the file name..

Comment: @Auxilus but why was that trying to import that String.py?? i mean, it should naturally look for in the libs folder ??

Answer (score 1):

there should be file named string.py in your current directory, renaming it should fix the problem.

From the docs:

> When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter searches for a
>   file named spam.py in the current directory, and then in the list of
>   directories specified by the environment variable PYTHONPATH. This has
>   the same syntax as the shell variable PATH, that is, a list of
>   directory names

so when one of your dependencies try to import string, program first look in the current directory and then in PYTHONPATH